# Grails 3 with @Value Annotation does not return null if it can't resolve property

Tags: java, grails, spring-boot

Grails 3.2.8 application using an application.properties file in src/main/resources folder and It works perfect if underlying spring is able to resolve property.

```
2017-04-18 15:01:09.957 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'com.win.test' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]] with type [String]

2017-04-18 15:01:09.957 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'com.win.test' in [environmentProperties] with type [String]
```

However, if property is not present in application.properties or application.yml file, shouldn't it return 'null'?

```
2017-04-18 15:01:09.956 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'widget.name' in any property source
```

Code Snippet of Service.

```
class TestService {

    @Value('${widget.name}')
    def name
    @Value('${com.win.test}')
    def test

    def serviceMethod() {
        println name
        println test
    }
}
```

Output:

```
${widget.name}
hello
```

So name should be resolved to null because widget.name does not exist in properties file but in this case it's value is expression of value Annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what value you want if the key is not present:

`@Value('${widget.name:#{NULL}}') 
def name`

Comment: This is not 'null'. Its a string. I could initialize name with 'null' but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: sorry, I wrote out of my laptop. Correct syntax is:
`@Value('${widget.name:#{NULL}}') def name`

Comment: Thanks Jorge but this still does not clear the concept. Why @value returning the "Placeholder"?